# Is it a good Practice to create Local Classes?

Tags: java, local-class

Most of the time i see that programmers say Local Classes are not good for some reasons and say instead of creating classes in methods, create new java files and use them. My question is, suppose that if i wanna create separate files for each class, finally it would be 100 java files that use of over 60 of them is just in one and one method. now what? is it still better to create those classes separately? Sometimes it happens that in one method we have some variables that have to be initialized by same statements. Is it good to create a private function in enclosed class and use it in the method or create a local class in the method?

Regards

Comment: It totally depends.

Comment: @DaveNewton but even when i post some code to take some advice from pros, and my code has local classes, they don't answer! they say simplify your code by getting the local class out of the method!

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing, how you're doing it, or why you're doing it, I'm not sure what you expect--can't provide any generally-meaningful advice without details. It's also subject to opinion, e.g., I only rarely use local classes, but it's more a preference.

Comment: @DaveNewton so local classes are good in some situations and that's on programmer, decide to use them or not. tnx. that helps a lot.

Comment: Local classes and top-level classes are not the only choices. Local classes are disruptive to maintainers reading method code. We're used to looking for procedure inside method code, and type outside. One use case might be to create function variables, if not using lambdas. _Why_ do you want them? What's the advantage? Why not create variables of anonymous class type outside the method? Please explain your engineering reasoning in detail.

Comment: "finally it would be 100 java files that use of over 60 of them is just in one and one method" If you really need 100 types, and didn't actually just screw up your type analysis, and they really all need to be used _in_ a method, each, rather than each having proper object-oriented behaviors, then you still need all that code to define those 100 non-OO classes regardless. Which is going to be easier to maintain, random unnamed types buried deep in procedural code, or neatly laid-out top-level type taxonomies?

Comment: @LewBloch I've done some research and it seems there's no *function variables* in java yet. But about anonymous class types, i didn't get it! you mean for example, if i want to initialize several field of a class in a method, and for initializing every single of them, a unique procedure must be executed, it's good to create an interface with one method, create a variable type of an anonymous class using the interface and then use the variable instead of doing the same with local classes?

Comment: Well what would you call `f1` in `Fun<C, Integer> f1 = C::size;`? (From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)

Comment: "But about anonymous class types, i didn't get it" No, I don't mean that. I mean if you have 100 classes each used in one place, you probably screwed up your type analysis, but if you didn't screw up, and for some reason you actually need 100 classes, then there is no way to escape writing 100 classes. Then the question becomes what is easier to maintain. It sounds like you need 100 sections of initialization block, though, and not 100 new types. What you describe doesn't sound like valid type analysis. Maybe you could provide a concrete example?

Comment: @LewBloch Now i see, i think my explanation has problem cause my question is a little bit different from what you said or my conclusions about what you're saying is wrong. For example, assume i need about 30 classes for my program. In some functions across these 30 classes, inside of them, i need to do some long-time or complex calculations to initialize more than one field of its enclosed class. BUT, it's not like all those fields being initialized once the method invoked, if there's 5 fields, then those long-time or complex calculations must execute 5 times!

Comment: @LewBloch Now, suppose i have 10-12 functions across these 30 classes like what i said. Now most of programmers say that creating local classes to implement those complex calculations, in these functions, is wrong and say i should create these classes as separate files. but these would add a lot of new java files which has one or two functions, without any fields, just to do those complex calculations.

Comment: @LewBloch So, my question is: "Is it really efficient to create all those java files?". i need to say i've not studied *function variables* yet.

Comment: If you have correctly identified the types your program needs, you will have to write code for all those types. How do rate "efficiency"? Runtime performance? No difference where the definitions go. Speed to write the code? Probably faster with non-local nested classes or top-level classes, if you account for time fixing and debugging mistakes, but not by much. Testing the code? Local classes lose majorly. Long-term maintenance? Non-local classes win big time. What is "efficiency" to you? I recommend preferring non-local classes unless you have a *strong* reason not to.

Comment: @LewBloch So you're suggesting to create all of those java files and let local-classes go. thanks for your help
My last question is, what about private nested classes? should i avoid them like local classes or they're fine to work with?